# read a large nested json file in R

Tags: r, json, nested

I am trying to read a json file in R and I have difficulty due to the structure as far as I understand; it is a large nested file.  I have tried several ways, sometimes it crashes without being able to understand what is the problem, but I am getting the impression the size of the file is also an issue? The json file is about 50 MB.  More specifically, from this

```
setwd("C:/Downloads")
   data <-fromJSON(file="tracks.json")
   json_data<-as.data.frame(data)
   print(json_data)
```

I am getting this error:

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

I gather this is because I have different number of rows and columns, but I cannot understand from other cases I have read how can I resolve the issue and eventually read the file to be able to analyse it. Actually, the problem starts when I am trying to convert the list to a dataframe (json_data<-as.data.frame(data)). I also tried

```
do.call(rbind, data)%>%
     as.data.frame
```

That crashed everything and

```
 rbindlist(data)
```

That gives me the following error

Error in rbindlist(data) : could not find function "rbindlist"

I have seen posts of people having similar issues, but I could not manage to relate exactly with mine or seemed extremely complicated for my limited knowledge; I am really new in R. Could anyone be so kind to provide some help?

the structure of the data looks like this:

```
[{
        "messageVersion": "3.1.0",
        "tracks": {
            "14942": {
                "path": [{
                    "point": {
                        "x": 394,
                        "y": 280,
                        "lat": 51.90160349662568,
                        "lng": -1.1548258756254903
                    },
                    "time": 1599648842873
                }, {
                    "point": {
                        "x": 381,
                        "y": 278,
                        "lat": 51.90159934078558,
                        "lng": -1.154825520298735
                    },
                    "time": 1599648842973,
                    "interp": true
                }, {
                    "point": {
                        "x": 369,
                        "y": 277,
                        "lat": 51.90159554832575,
                        "lng": -1.1548248322945749
                    },
                    "time": 1599648843065
                }, {
                    "point": {
                        "x": 355,
                        "y": 275,
                        "lat": 51.90159106769861,
                        "lng": -1.154824382392153
                    },
                    "time": 1599648843165,
                    "interp": true
                }
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: The issue is not the size but rather the irregular number columns per row. You should consider having it as a list rather than a dataframe.

Comment: thank you very much for your response! I Judging from the json file, it has many levels and that complicates things. The problem is that I need to do quite a lot of data manipulation and I am not familiar with working with lists. Could you please recommend any source or reference to read more specifically about that? I have done some research online, but could I did not manage to find something really helpful. Thank you in advace.